# How can I get rid of one animation in a media query?

Tags: html, css, animation, media

I have two different css animations affecting the same word. This is the code I use for it:

```
#welcome{
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #00FFFF;
    animation: welcomeAnimation infinite 4s,rotate 2s;/*2 animations*/
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
```

When the width of the device browser is less than 800px, I only want the animation "welcomeAnimation" to play. I use a media query like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
#welcome{
        font-size: 80px;
        color: #00FFFF;
        animation: welcomeAnimation infinite 4s;/*1 animation*/
        animation-delay: 0s;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        }
}
```

Both animations still play when I do this. How can I keep both animations as a default, but when the screen is less, play only one animation?

Comment: mind to write your css comment as css comments, not js comments ;)

Comment: are these the exact selectors you are using, or did you simplify them for your example here? are both blocks in the same file? if so, which comes first in the file? if not, which file is loaded first? (i'm wondering if its a specificity issue.)

Comment: Oops. I just added the comments for explanation. I used the exact selectors. Both are in the same file. The media query comes second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with the code you've posted, besides the syntax of your comments. I've put it into a working demo below.

```css
@keyframes welcomeAnimation {
  0% { color: #00FFFF; }
  50% { color: #008888; }
  100% { color: #00FFFF; }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  50% { transform: rotate(-45deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

#welcome {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #00FFFF;
  animation: welcomeAnimation infinite 4s, rotate infinite 2s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #welcome {
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #00FFFF;
    animation: welcomeAnimation infinite 4s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="welcome">
  Welcome
</div>
```

I've made one small change, just to make the effect easier to notice: I added "infinite" to the rotate animation. This isn't necessary to solve the problem.

Notice that if you run the snippet here in the answer, there is only one animation (since the snippet window is less than 800px wide) -- but if you launch it full page, it has both animations.

Or you can view the same demo on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeuL4mbe/), where you can drag and resize the preview window to activate or de-activate the second animation.

So why didn't it work for you? It's probably a specificity issue, or it's because you are inserting comments with the wrong syntax.

If you have any comments in your real code that use a double-slash syntax, remove them and instead use comments that begin with `/*` and end with `*/`.

If that doesn't fix the issue, you can test to see whether it's a specificity issue by changing your animation property inside the media query to use the [`!important` exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception), like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #welcome {
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #00FFFF;
    animation: welcomeAnimation infinite 4s !important;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
}
```

If that fixes your problem, then you have a specificity issue.

**Do not leave the `!important` exception in your code.** This exception is a useful debugging tool, but using it in production code will cause you headaches down the line.

Instead, read up on [how to resolve specificity issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) on the MDN.

In your case:

1. Make sure the "normal version" and the media-queried version both use the same CSS selector. In the example you've posted here, they both simply use `#welcome` -- that is good. If you really want them to have different selectors, the media-queried one should be more specific than the other.
2. Make sure the media-queried version is processed by the browser after the "normal version". If both sets of rules are in the same file, that just means putting the media-queried set of rules after the default set of rules. If they are in separate files, that means linking the media-queried file *after* the default file in your HTML.

Comment: You are right - it works. I don't know what was happening before. I added the comments when asking question - they are not the cause of whatever problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

Firs you have unset the **First** `animation` and then apply it again with another keyframe.

**NOTE:** Check the media queries, to execute must. that will be an issue also.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/5abr0v7q/)**

```
animation: none;

animation: welcomeAnimation infinite 4s;//1 animation
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
```

Comment: this doesn't seem right. do you have a source that backs this up?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation1
check this site, try to add `animation:none` then press `See Result` at top it works there.

Comment: in CSS, any time you set a new value for a property, it completely overrides the old value. so setting a property to `none` before giving it a new value is completely unnecessary.